# element dislocate itself after adding anotherone inside

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've got a group of three elements. Section, that contain a header and a div element. Now what I want to do is to add another div element within the div element, but when I do that both elements move down (dislocate from when they supposed to be).

HTML:

```
    <div class="main"><!-- main container -->
        <section class="head"><!-- header section -->
            <header  class="img_header">
                <img src="../img/d.jpg">
            </header>
            <div id="head_container">
                <div class="side_header">
                    <h class="mark">Damian</h> Tuszynski<br>
                    Network Solutions Architect
                    <p>
                        Mobile<br>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Email<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </section><!-- header section -->
</div>
```

CSS, for the header group:

```
.head {
border: 1px solid green;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:1900px;
    height:900px; 
}


  .img_header {
    border: 1px solid black;    
    display: inline-block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: #E8E2E2;
    position: relative;

 }

  #head_container {
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 900px;

  }


 .img_header img {

    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 300px;
    margin-left: 280px;
    position: relative;

  }

  .side_header {

    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;

  }

  .mark {

    color: #A1E3D8;

  }
```

what am I missing here?

```css
.head {
border: 1px solid green;
 white-space: nowrap;
 width:1900px;
 height:900px; 
}


  .img_header {
  border: 1px solid black; 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #E8E2E2;
  position: relative;

 }

  #head_container {
   border: 1px solid orange;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 1250px;
   height: 900px;

  }


 .img_header img {

   width: 230px;
   height: 230px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: block;
   margin-top: 300px;
   margin-left: 280px;
   position: relative;

  }

  .side_header {

   border: 1px solid blue;
   width: 1250px;
   height: 400px;
   position: relative;
   display: block;

  }

  .mark {

   color: #A1E3D8;

  }
```

```html
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="head"><!-- header section -->
   <header  class="img_header">
    <img src="../img/d.jpg">
   </header>
   <div id="head_container">
    <div class="side_header">
     <h class="mark">John</h> Snow<br>
     Network Solutions Architect
     <p>
      Mobile<br>
     </p>
     <p>
      Email<br>
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>   
  </section><!-- header section -->

  
</body>
```

Comment: I put your source in a fiddle, but apparently my monitor isn't big enough to visualise the problem properly. Lots of scrollbars. So, can you make a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Please also tell us which browser and platform to look on.

Comment: Could you create fiddles for "before" (working) and "after" (not working)?

Comment: I'm just figuring out how does that fiddling thing work.

Comment: OK, as I apparently can't add Fiddles to the posts anymore, I've added a Snipped which is pretty much the same thing. As you can see that div with orange border containing data like name etc. is moved out of it's container and it shoud be side by side with the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are making both header and div as inline-block they should be side-by-side ,but as you adding an image in the header the next div is moving . The best way to do this is to use display:flex

check this snippet

```css
.head {
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1900px;
  height: 900px;
  display: flex;
}
.img_header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #E8E2E2;
}
#head_container {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 900px;
}
.img_header img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 280px;
}
.side_header {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.mark {
  color: #A1E3D8;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="head">
    <!-- header section -->
    <header class="img_header">
      <img src="../img/d.jpg">
    </header>
    <div id="head_container">
      <div class="side_header">
        <h class="mark">John</h>Snow
        <br>Network Solutions Architect
        <p>
          Mobile
          <br>
        </p>
        <p>
          Email
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- header section -->


</body>
```

Solution without flex,is to use display:table and make every content within it as display:table-cell

check this snippet

```css
.head {
  border: 1px solid green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1900px;
  height: 900px;
  display: table;
}
.img_header {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: #E8E2E2;
}
#head_container {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 900px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.img_header img {
  width: 230px;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 280px;
}
.side_header {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 400px;
}
.mark {
  color: #A1E3D8;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="head">
    <!-- header section -->
    <header class="img_header">
      <img src="../img/d.jpg">
    </header>
    <div id="head_container">
      <div class="side_header">
        <h class="mark">John</h>Snow
        <br>Network Solutions Architect
        <p>
          Mobile
          <br>
        </p>
        <p>
          Email
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- header section -->


</body>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, a lot! It helped a great deal.